# ERROR NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed , *ngFor

Tags: angular, dictionary, ngfor, angular-directive, rxjs6

I've been trying to follow some similar questions and their solutions on the forum but can't figure out how to iterate my Object or assign it to the type properly for the view and fill the instance of the object type.

I'm able to see the correct object I want in the console log, but I can't iterate over it to populate the view. I tried keyvalue, however, I got stuck with the view just iterating over the whole object using {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}, I needed the data to match the model. I don't need the whole API response JSON object, just 'specific' property:values.

What I am not understanding? or What am I not doing? I've read the rxjs map information and angular.io keyvalue docs. Is it a typescript misunderstanding? Thanks in advance for your insight!

Component

```
export class ArtifactCardComponent implements OnInit {
  allArtifacts: Artifact[] = []; // Is this a class object type to array?
  isFetching: boolean = false;

  constructor(private artifactService: ArtifactService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.artifactService.getArtifacts().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return data['data'] ;
      }
    ))
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.isFetching = true;
        this.allArtifacts = data 
        console.log(artifacts);
        this.isFetching = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
      }
    );  
  }
}
```

Model:

```
export class Artifact {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  date_start: number;
  date_end: number;
  artist_display: string;
  main_reference_number: number;
  place_of_origin: string;
  medium_display: string;
  inscriptions: string;
  dimensions: number;
  credit_line: string;
  department_title: string;
}
```

Service:

```
public getArtifacts() {
 // return this.http.get<Artifact[]>(this.baseURL) : Observable<Artifact[]
 return this.http.get(this.baseURL,  { responseType: 'json' })
}
```

View:

```
<div>
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush d-flex align-items-start" 
*ngFor="let artifact of allArtifacts"  >
<li class="list-group-item  border-bottom-0">{{artifact.title}}<span></span></li>
...

</ul>
</div>
```

response

```
   {
    "id": 120081,
    "api_model": "artworks",
    "api_link": "https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/120081",
    "is_boosted": false,
    "title": "Landscape with Dog",
    "alt_titles": null,
    "thumbnail": {
        "lqip": ...,
        "width": 2721,
        "height": 2250,
        "alt_text": "A work made of oil on composition board."
    },
    "main_reference_number": "1990.485",
    "has_not_been_viewed_much": false,
    "boost_rank": null,
    "date_start": 1832,
    "date_end": 1832,
    "date_display": "1832",
    "date_qualifier_title": "",
    "date_qualifier_id": null,
    "artist_display": "Thomas Doughty\nAmerican, 1793–1856",
    "place_of_origin": "United States",
    "dimensions": "24.8 × 29.2 cm (9 3/4 × 11 1/2 in.)",
    "medium_display": "Oil on composition board",
    "inscriptions": "signed l.r.: \"TD/1832\"",
    "credit_line": "Through prior acquisition of the Charles H. and Mary F. S. Worcester Collection",
    "catalogue_display": null,
    "publication_history": "Alexander Gallery (advertisement) in Magazine Antiques, 88, 5 (November 1990) p. 860 (ill.).",
    "exhibition_history": null,
    "provenance_text": null,
    "publishing_verification_level": "Web Cataloged",
    "internal_department_id": 21,
    "fiscal_year": 1991,
    "fiscal_year_deaccession": null,
    "is_public_domain": true,
    "is_zoomable": true,
    "max_zoom_window_size": -1,
    "copyright_notice": null,
    "has_multimedia_resources": false,
    "has_educational_resources": false,
    "has_advanced_imaging": false,
    "colorfulness": 29.5929,
    "color": {
   ...
    },
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "latlon": null,
    "is_on_view": false,
    "on_loan_display": null,
    "gallery_title": null,
    "gallery_id": null,
    "artwork_type_title": "Painting",
    "artwork_type_id": 1,
    "department_title": "Arts of the Americas",
    "department_id": "PC-3",
    "artist_id": 43088,
    "artist_title": "Thomas Doughty",
    "alt_artist_ids": [],
    "artist_ids": [
        43088
    ],
    "artist_titles": [
        "Thomas Doughty"
    ],
    "category_ids": [
        "PC-3"
    ],
    "category_titles": [
        "Arts of the Americas"
    ],
    "term_titles": [
...
    ]....
}
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON response that you received to the question? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the JSON response before mapping it. You can do this with `this.http.get(this.baseURL, { responseType: 'json' }).pipe(tap(data => console.log(data)))`. By the way, the responseType Json is the default, so you don't need the option parameter.

Comment: ok thank you , I'll provide for that feeback

Comment: I've added the json

Comment: Hi @user2920627, is the response data you attached the complete one? From your response: I have these concerns: 1. Your response doesn't contain the `data` property which you try to extract with the `map` rxjs, hence you will get `undefined`. 2. If the attached response is the complete one, the response is an object (`Artifact`) but not an array (`Artifact[]`). Please review and rectify it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys , I figured it out .  I was forcing the use of a directive that didnt need - *ngFor . I already assigned my response to the object type, so could bind directly to view my template input variable {{ object.value}}. I was over complicating the issue